# PhpStorm - как настроить SCSS watcher - чтобы в CSS файле были комментарии - на какой строке SASS написан стиль?

Tags: phpstorm, sass

Когда я компилирую SCSS файлы вот таким способом:

```
compass watch scss/main.scss
```

(это bat команда) то у меня в получившемся CSS файле пишутся строки - из какой строки SCSS файла получился стиль на данной строчке. Вот, например:

```
/* line 176, ../scss/css_header.scss */
```

Когда компилирую через PhpStorm watcher, у меня этих комментариев в CSS файле нет. Как сделать, чтобы они были?

Вот скриншот настроек watcher в PhpStorm:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: За создание комментариев отвечает опция `line_comments = true` в `config.rb`. Похоже, ваш вотчер каким-то образом настроен так, что compass игнорирует эту опцию. Трудно сказать, как вам это удалось. Пожалуйста, приложите скриншот настроек вотчера

Comment: @lena, поправил вопрос.

Comment: попробуйте использовать compass вместо sass в вотчере:) Вы используете разные компиляторы и почему-то удивляетесь, что результаты не совпадают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы получить тот же результат, что и в командной строке, надо file watcher настроить соответствующим образом. Если вы хотите использовать **scss.bat**, попробуйте передавать ему опцию `--line-comments`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или настройте **compass.bat** в качестве file watcher - он будет читать `line_comments = true` из `config.rb`, как это происходит, когда вы его запускаете в терминале